# Chrome extension - Change content with javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a basic chrome extension, that opens a popup with a simple select menu, which on change executes a javascript. Simple right?

```
    <script src="popup2.js"></script>
    <select id="MySelectMenu" onchange="newSrc()">
                     <option value="http://electro.piratefm.ro/popup.html" >Electro</option>
                     <option value="http://rap.piratefm.ro/popup.html" >Rap</option>
                     <option value="http://dub.piratefm.ro/popup.html" >Dub</option>
    </select>

    <iframe src="http://electro.piratefm.ro/popup.html" frameborder="0" width="302" height="75" style="float:left" id="MyFrame"></iframe>
```

and of course popup2.js

```
function newSrc(){
document.getElementById('MyFrame').innerHTML= '<iframe src="#" width="100" height="100"></iframe>';
}
```

I click on the icon, the popup starts fine, music starts playing, but when I change an option it just won't delete, or change the content of the iframe.

Comment: _Please_ read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then edit out irrelevant parts of your question ("Here's the deal", "halp pls", "Sorry" etc.) and avoid them in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`innerHTML` will only change children, not the element itself.

To fix, wrap it in a container.

```
<div id="MyFrameContainer">
  <iframe src="http://electro.piratefm.ro/popup.html" frameborder="0" width="302" height="75" style="float:left" id="MyFrame"></iframe>
</div>
```

and

```
function newSrc(){
  document.getElementById('MyFrameContainer').innerHTML= '<iframe src="#" width="100" height="100"></iframe>';
}
```

---

Apart from that, use of `onchange` in an element counts as inline JS, which is [not allowed by the default CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution).

You should remove it and bind the event handler dynamically from your popup2.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
   document.getElementById('MySelectMenu').addEventListener('change', newSrc);
});
```

Comment: Then describe clearly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to make a menu pop up, and when you choose an option, a certain iframe is opened on the background page. It wasn't working so I tried making it work on the popup first. Basically what I want is that when you choose an option from the menu, an iframe with the url as the value of the selection is opened instead of the one that was already open. I know how to do that stuff but it wasn't working so I tried something simpler, open the frame and when something is selected, close it.

Comment: Now, define "not working". Your `newSrc` makes no use of the selected option, by the way.

Comment: not working as in when I select something else, the frame doesn't disappear, aka get changed to one with # as src

Comment: Ah, I finally got what is wrong. Updated my answer; for the future, please refer to this helpful guide on debugging popups: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging

Comment: thanks a lot, now it's working. I didn't even guess that would count as inline js, I've read all about it but still. and if you could hang around for a couple more minutes it would be great

Comment: And that's why I linked to the debugging tutorial. You would read the complaint in the console that inline JS was the culprit.

Comment: So I've changed it to use the info from the value now, but after moving some stuff, it's not working again. Take a look, this is the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null . I have no idea how to properly indent code in a comment, how can I talk to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56127/discussion-between-xan-and-user3693892).